# Cohen Quantum Mechanics Derivation?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, schroedinger-equation, fourier-transform, time-evolution

I dont understand the argument on page 38 eq. (C-6) of Cohen's quantum mechanics. Could someone break down for me what is $g(k)$? Is it the initial condition?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you set $t=0$ in C-6, you get
$$
\psi(\vec{r}) = \frac{1}{(2\pi)^{3/2}}\int d^3 k\ g(\vec{k}) e^{i\vec{k}\cdot\vec{r}}
$$
Then it is clear that $g(\vec{k})$ is the Fourier transform of $\psi(\vec{r})$, which is the "initial state" or if you prefer "initial condition" for the wave function.

For general $t$, we make use of the fact that you can evolve any initial wave function by expressing it as a superposition of energy eigenfunctions, which have a simple time dependence. In general, assuming the potential is time independent, we have
$$
\psi(\vec{r}, t) = \sum_n a_n u_n(\vec{r}) e^{-i \omega_n t}
$$
where the sum over $n$ is schematic here -- it is a sum for discrete energy eigenvalues, and an integral for continuous energy eigenvalues.

For a free particle, the mode functions $u_n(\vec{r})$ are just $\frac{1}{(2\pi)^{3/2}} e^{i \vec{k} \cdot\vec{r}}$. The label of the mode functions, $\vec{k}$, is a continuous parameter, so we need to integrate instead of sum. Accounting for all this, the expansion becomes
$$
\psi(\vec{r}, t) = \frac{1}{(2\pi)^{3/2}}\int d^3 k\ g(\vec{k}) e^{i \left[\vec{k}\cdot \vec{r} - \omega(k) t\right]}
$$
In this context, the function $g(k)$ is analogous to the coefficients $a_n$ in the sum above -- they are coefficients in the expansion of $\psi(\vec{r}, t)$ over energy eigenfunctions. Just for completeness, we also note that the integral $\int d^3 k$ is analogous to the sum $\sum_n$; the mode functions $\frac{1}{(2\pi)^{3/2}} e^{i \vec{k}\cdot \vec{r}}$ are analogous to the functions $u_n(\vec{r})$ above; and the time dependence of each mode $e^{-i \omega t}$ appears in both expressions.

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking at is the [Fourier transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_transform) of a function, although the author is showing you that this amounts to taking a continuous superposition (as opposed to a discrete [Fourier Series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_series)). G(k) is the momentum space representation of the wave function for the free particle in this case.

Comment: It's true that $g(k)$ is the Fourier transform of $\psi(x)$ at $t=0$. For $t\neq 0$, I don't think it's quite the Fourier transform. I would say in that case $g(k)$ represents the coefficients in a mode expansion for $\psi(x,t)$.

Comment: Andrew, what makes you say it's not quite the Fourier transform? Aside from this statement what we are saying is equivalent.

Comment: The factor of $e^{-i \omega(k) t}$ makes it not a Fourier transform. (a) In a three dimensional Fourier transform, you wouldn't have this factor. (b) In a four dimensional Fourier transform, $\omega$ would be independent of $k$ and you would integrate over $\omega$.

Comment: Oh I see what you're saying, yeah, it's the Fourier transform at t=0 but to recover the full transform for all t is rather trivial.